# If you are doubting of Abhidhamma so long, please keep those questions on, and ask whatever conflicts you think you found in Abhidhamma to me

Tags: discussion

If you are doubting of  Abhidhamma so long,  please keep those questions on, and ask whatever conflicts you think you found in Abhidhamma to me.

And I think to understand the main problem of the conflict you think you have in abhidhamma first, please read my answer [in this questions first](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/45456/abhidhamma-is-craving-really-the-samudaya-of-suffering/45465#45465). Most of doubts in Abhidhamma began from that simple point.

Metta ^.^